# undefined reference to glcolor3f & glutSwapBuffers & glutInit etc

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, codeblocks, glut

I am working on a project on OpenGl using codeblocks on Ubuntu 14.04, although I am sure I have downloaded the Gl/glut library, here is the error I keep getting when I compile the code:

```
||=== Build: Debug in CAnko (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/main.o||In function `display()':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|9|undefined reference to `glClear'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/main.o||In function `mouse(int, int, int, int)':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|27|undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/main.o||In function `main':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|33|undefined reference to `glutInit'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|34|undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|35|undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|36|undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|37|undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|38|undefined reference to `glClearColor'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|39|undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|40|undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|41|undefined reference to `glOrtho'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|42|undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|43|undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/main.cpp|44|undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.o||In function `Painter::drawClosedField(int, int)':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|9|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|10|undefined reference to `glBegin'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|11|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|12|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|13|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|14|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|15|undefined reference to `glEnd'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|16|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|17|undefined reference to `glBegin'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|18|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|19|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|20|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|21|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|22|undefined reference to `glEnd'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|23|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|24|undefined reference to `glBegin'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|25|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|26|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|27|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|28|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|29|undefined reference to `glEnd'|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.o||In function `Painter::drawOpenedField(int, int, int)':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|40|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|43|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|46|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|49|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|52|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.o:/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|55|more undefined references to `glColor3f' follow|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.o||In function `Painter::drawOpenedField(int, int, int)':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|64|undefined reference to `glRasterPos2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|65|undefined reference to `glutBitmap9By15'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|65|undefined reference to `glutBitmapCharacter'|
obj/Debug/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.o||In function `Painter::drawFlag(int, int)':|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|71|undefined reference to `glColor3f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|72|undefined reference to `glBegin'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|73|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|74|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
/home/canonder/Desktop/minesweeper/painter.cpp|75|undefined reference to `glVertex2f'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Here is the whole main code:

```
#include "game.hpp"
#include "painter.hpp"
#include <GL/glut.h>

Game game;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    game.draw();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        switch (button)
        {
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            game.open(x / Painter::CELL_WIDTH, y / Painter::CELL_HEIGHT);
            break;
        case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
            game.mark(x / Painter::CELL_WIDTH, y / Painter::CELL_HEIGHT);
            break;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(Game::WIDTH * Painter::CELL_WIDTH, Game::HEIGHT * Painter::CELL_HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 120);
    glutCreateWindow("MineSweeper");
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Game::HEIGHT * Painter::CELL_HEIGHT, Game::WIDTH * Painter::CELL_WIDTH, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Could you please reference the same question before tagging it as a duplicate? That would help the community better than what you are trying to do right now..

Comment: The libs you must link are at least 'gl, glut'
Project->Build options->Linker settings

Comment: i have downloaded glut libraries on ubuntu using these
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
on terminal i can see the libraries. (usr/include/gl) even though i gave the same directory on linker settings i see no libraries

Comment: Headers (.h) are not libraries (.so). Just add their names (e.g. "gl") to C::B project settings